# Combining two pure functions

Tags: function-construction

How to get from the following intermediate result to the final one with just one pure function?

```
data = {"2894;Hot Pink;53:09:44;1449714", 
   "17456;Dark Cyan;19:06:42;6929227", "5147;Lime;54:11:55;5247632"};  
  from = 2; to = 3; delim = ";"; nr = to - from + 1;  

inter = StringSplit[#, delim][[from ;; to]] & /@ data  
{{"Hot Pink", "53:09:44"}, {"Dark Cyan", "19:06:42"}, {"Lime", "54:11:55"}}  

final = {{"Hot Pink;53:09:44"}, {"Dark Cyan;19:06:42"}, {"Lime;54:11:55"}}
```

Comment: Can't you just join the strings ? You can use `Riffle` to insert the `;`.

Comment: I see that you have not Accepted my answer.  If you find it lacking tell me, and I'll try to improve it.  If not, please consider Accepting it (green check-mark). See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428)

Answer (score 9):

Using only one `Function`:

```
{# <> ";" <> #2} & @@@ StringSplit[data, delim][[All, from ;; to]]
```

Perhaps more robustly:

```
{"" <> Riffle[#, ";"]} & /@ 
  StringSplit[data, delim][[All, from ;; to]]
```

Using the `Listable` form of `StringSplit` as shown above should be faster in any case.

---

Just for fun, without `Function` at all:

```
StringJoin /@ StringSplit[data, ";" -> ";"][[All, 3 ;; 5]]
```

> ```
> {"Hot Pink;53:09:44", "Dark Cyan;19:06:42", "Lime;54:11:55"}
> ```

Turning this "fun" method into a usable solution which proves quite fast:

```
List /@ StringJoin /@ 
  StringSplit[data, delim -> delim][[All, 2 from - 1 ;; 2 to - 1]]
```

Comment: Very good.  .  .  .Interesting to compare your functional sulution with a algorithmically one. In one setting.  .  .1.000.000 records were treated.  .  .Yours: 33.899 sec.  .the other: 20.78sec.  .  .On an differend setting also 1.000.000 records treated.  .  .Yours: 7.7sec.  .  .the other: 13.6sec

Comment: @HpR Which methods are you comparing?

Comment: A first method reads in from external source one line by line.
Acts on it and append it to disk.
Thats for very large segments that wont fit in memory at ones.  
The second one reads in the whole raw segment.
Acts on it and writes it to disk.
This is for segments that fit in memory at ones. 
(and what was ask for in the first place)

I used your function unchanged for both methods.